# How can I wrap by controller for views in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to use `parentController` like the below code, is it possible?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main.base', {
            abstract : true,
        views : {
                'left@main' : {
                    templateUrl: '',
                    controller : ''
                },
            'content-head@main': {
                templateUrl: '',
                controller: ''
            },
            'content-body@main': {
                template : '<div>init page</div>'
            }
        },
        params : {

        },
        controller: 'ParentController as parentCtrl'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is, but you need a parent state. Eg;

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        controller: 'ParentController as parentCtrl'
    })
    .state('main.base', {
        // your views
    });
```

If you have views, you can't have a controller on the same state, but you can always add a state in your hierarchy to achieve the same result.